# Help with Hashcat?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm trying to get hashcat running, but seem to be having some issues.

I'm following this guide for Ubuntu:
https://techglimpse.com/password-cracking-with-hashcat/

Using this installer:
https://hashcat.net/files/hashcat-3.10.7z

In addition to the guide, I did:

```
install ocl-icd-libopencl1
apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this error on the included example files:

```
root@ip-139-28-11-15:~/new/hashcat-3.10# hashcat example0.hash example.dict
hashcat (v3.10) starting...

Generating bitmap tables with 16 bits...

ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

My OS is:

```
Linux ip-139-28-11-15 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I don't know what to do.  Any help?

Comment: Bump.  Any one?  I'm still looking for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Intel CPUs require OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors (16.1.1 or later). Download and install OpenCL™ Runtime latest from intel website. Ignore the compatibility warning.

Source: https://youtu.be/AieYqNQ6ADM

Answer (score 0):

I just built hashcat on ubuntu 16 using the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat.git
sudo apt install hashcat
sudo apt install cmake build-essential
sudo apt build-dep hashcat
cd hashcat
git submodule update --init
make
ls
./hashcat  --version
```